# @Validated/@Valid exclude default group from being validated

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

this is my class which I use in `CreateAccountRequest` and `ChangeCompanyDetailsRequest`.

```
public class CompanyDetails {

    @NotNull(groups = { CreateAccount.class })
    private String companyName;
    @NotNull(groups = { CreateAccount.class })
    private String registrationNumber;
    private String taxId;

    ...
}
```

I have this methods signatures:

```
@PostMapping
void createAccount(@RequestBody @Validated(value = { CreateAccount.class }) CreateAccountRequest request);

@PutMapping
void changeCompanyDetails(@RequestBody @Validated(value = { ChangeCompanyDetails.class }) ChangeCompanyDetailsRequest request);
```

where `CreateAccount.class` and `ChangeCompanyDetails.class` are simple interfaces without any methods/annotations.

When I call createAccount and companyName or registrationNumber is null then violations are raised and when I call changeCompanyDetails without companyName or registrationName the violations are raised too. In later case I don't want to validate the constraints. Do I understand it correctly that if I specify group the validator should validate only that group if present? In this case I think the validation is called for default group.

Thanks

Comment: The Validated annotation is set on a parameter of type ChangeCompanyDetailsRequest. But the NotNull validation annotations are in the class CompanyDetails, so the group specified in the Validated annotation is irrelevant.

Comment: CompanyDetails is inside CreateAccountRequest ans also ChangeCompanyDetailsRequest so that means I need to annotate CompanyDetails field with @Validated annotation an put there group?

Comment: Not sure about that, but it's probably it, yes.